# How to have an autocmd not interfer with saved sessions?

Tags: vim, vi, autocmd

I have `autocmd BufEnter * silent! lcd %:p:h` in my .vimrc so that the current buffer's pwd is always set correctly.  Unfortunately `mksession` does not save sessions properly because of this.

Is there either a better way to save sessions, or a way to make these two features play together well?  Disabling the autocmd temporarily with `:noautocmd mksession session1` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What does "does not save sessions properly" exactly mean? I'd guess the session file is still written, but you encounter some problems during session load?!

Comment: when the session saves the paths of all buffers, it assumes they are all in the pwd.  Loading the corrupt session without loading my .vimrc, hence no autocmd, confirms this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
:set autochdir
```

will do the same as your autocmd, and is built-in. I'm using that one myself, and haven't encountered any problems with sessions. Of course, the directory that the session is saved to must be specified relative to the current file, though you could define a custom `:Mksession` command that is always based on a fixed directory.

Comment: had to update my vim to get that feature, but it works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From the `:help`:

```
                        *SessionLoad-variable*
While the session file is loading the SessionLoad global variable is set to 1.
Plugins can use this to postpone some work until the SessionLoadPost event is
triggered.
```

You could try modifying your autocmd to do nothing if `g:SessionLoad` exists and is set to 1.

But I think Ingo's solution, using `set autochdir`, is better.